# How can i make this code loop in Python

Tags: python

This code is supposed to turn decimals into binary, i figured out that part but now i need the code to go back to the previous question of asking to type in a integer instead of closing the program when calculations are done.

Here is what i have so far

```
def binary(n):

   if n > 1:
       binary(n//2)
       print(n % 2,end = '')



dec = int(input("Enter an integer: "))
binary(dec)


 input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")
```

Comment: A simple google search for the syntax for different types of looping in python should return all of the answers you need.

Comment: SO is not the right place for asking questions about basic syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Both a *for loop* and a *while loop* would help you to achieve the required outcome, depending on how many times you want the statement to loop. If you know the amount of times, use a for loop, however if you are comparing it do a condition, a while loop would probably be best. Find the syntax for for loops in python [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop)

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a simple while loop. It checks to see if the condition is true, and then executes the nested code. Therefore, putting True as the condition will make it an infinite loop.

```
def binary(n):    
    if n > 1:
        binary(n//2)
        string print(n % 2,end = '')


while True:
    dec = int(input("Enter an integer: "))
    binary(dec)


input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")
```